# preg_replace - $1 returns capture group AND also the rest

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can use `preg_replace` on `95040` so that only the first character is kept?

This is my attempt which should work like [my online regex](https://regex101.com/r/lU7j4q/1) shows

[image]

but I get the original string back.

```
$re = '/(^\d{1})/m';
$str = '9100';

$str = preg_replace($re, '$1', $str);
echo $str;  //returns 9100
```

What am I doing wrong?

[onlinePhp](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62f3b4be3bda980bb4e48d726878c2901b446aa5)

---

**UPDATE**

I noticed that the following code returns `9-->100` instead of `9`:

```
$re = '/(^\d)/';
$str = '9100';

$str = preg_replace($re, '$1-->', $str);
echo $str; //returns 9-->100
```

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

[onlinePhp](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3644d7ac78b02a648238abce34cb604f5ceadd22)

Comment: Add `.*` at the end of the pattern and replace `m` with `s`. However, it is hardly a job for a regex, it is a mere string operation.

Comment: Why not just `$str[0]` ?

Comment: Why do you need regex when you can simply do `$str[0]` do get first character?

Comment: (`{1}` is entirely superfluous.)

Comment: @Arvind,+CD001 because I developed a function which accepts regex as a optional parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply Do:-

```
$str = $str[0];
```

Output:-https://eval.in/991817

***If you want `preg_replace()` anyhow:-***

```
<?php

$re = '/(^\d).*/s';
$str = '9100';

$str = preg_replace($re, '$1', $str);
echo $str;
```

Output:- https://eval.in/991829

Comment: I still don't understand why `/(^\d)/` does not work too, `preg_replace($re, '$1-->', $str);` returns `9-->100` instead of `9`. Maybe a fail in the design of PHP regex?! My screenshot shows that it should work (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iInyd.png)

Comment: You regex pattern only matches 1-character (a number) and that is the only part of the match that is modified. Your screenshot shows the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
substr($txt, 0, 1)
```

This will output `$txt` string first char.